# Passing arguments conditionally to R functions

Tags: r, function

I have an existing function `pass_thru(target,...)` that passes arguments to other functions (let's say, `a()`, `b()`, and `c()`) depending on its inputs. For example:

```
> target <- "a"
> arg1 <- "some input"
> arg2 <- "other input"
> pass_thru(target, arg1)
# This passes ellipses arguments to function `a()`
```

I would like to pass `arg2` to my function, but only if `target == b`, because none of the other functions can accept `arg2` (i.e. `arg2 = NULL` does not work). Additionally, I can't make changes to `pass_thru()`.

The desired effect is the below, but without having to repeat `pass_thru()`.

```
> if (target == "b") { pass_thru(target, arg1, arg2) }
  else { pass_thru(target, arg1) }
```

--
The actual code I'm running is from the `caret` package. `verbose` is the argument that breaks the function when `method = "glm"`.

```
train(y ~ x, data,
      method = TARGET,
      trControl = ARG1,
      verbose = ARG2)
```

Comment: Is it possible to share a dummy of `pass_thru`?

Comment: What is the problem with repeating `pass_thru`?  It only gets evaluated once in any case, so there's no runtime penalty

Comment: I'm writing a function that will create many models for me. I don't want to change both instances of `pass_thru()` every time I have an edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a wrapper function that dispatches the correct number of arguments to `pass_thru`.  Here's a dummy example to demonstrate

```
pass_thru = function(t, ...){
  a = function(arg1,arg2) paste(arg1,arg2)
  b = function(arg1) paste(arg1)
  get(t)(...)
}


pass_wrapper = function(target, ...){
  dots = list(...)
  if (target != 'a') dots[2] <- NULL
  do.call(pass_thru, c(target, dots))
}

pass_wrapper("a", arg1, arg2)
# "some input other input"
pass_wrapper("b", arg1, arg2)
# "some input"
```